# how decode and encode image from jsonplaceholder API

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, base64, swifty-json

I want through this API
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/3
display Image from `"url"` by swiftyJson 
I wrote this code, but is return nil

```
var base64String = subDataJSON["url"].stringValue
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
self.MyImage.image = decodedIamge! as UIImage
```

how do I bring Images from API? Are all the images in APIs  handled by the same way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that code work? As I can see from the response of the API http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/3

```
{
  "albumId": 1,
  "id": 3,
  "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
  "url": "http://placehold.it/600/24f355",
  "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/1941e9"
}
```

Basically, the what you have done on this code `subDataJSON["url"].stringValue` is that you retrieve the value of "url" node, it will return "http://placehold.it/600/24f355". So, I think it is not a base64 string as your expectation. Instead of calling

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

try this code

```
let decodedData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: base64String))
```

However, this might blocks your UI thread as we are calling synchronized. A better approach would be

```
let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "")!) { (
            data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let imageView = self.MyImage {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }

        };

        dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works !! But please I want to ask you , What if the image is preserved in API as String? how decoded from base64 to UIImage? because my friend will write API for me and he said the images will back as String and I should decoded to use it in my App, how can I do that? Is there any ready APi with string image for testing code ?

Comment: Here is the code of encoding image to base 64 string and decoding 64 string to image

//UIImage to Base64 String
        let image: UIImage = yourImage;
        let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        
        //Decode Base64 String to UIImage
        let base64String = "base64String";
        let decodedImageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
        let decodedImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodedImageData)